# Remove Resque worker class caching and avoid worker restart everytime code is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, resque

I have a code which pushes a resque job in Rails.

in that job class, the only thing I do is

```
Resque.logger.info("Hello");
```

After I start my Resque workers and make changes to the job code file eg:

```
Resque.logger.info("Can I see this?");
```

I am unable to see the changes reflected in Resque logger, it still says "Hello" unless I restart my workers.
Is there any way to avoid restarting the resque workers everytime I make changes to my job file. In short, I want to be dynamically able to change my code and probably run a faster command to reflect my chagnes for the next job to be processed.

I've also kept

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

in all my environment config files.

Comment: Ideally not since resque load the environment at start if you want to achieve this perhaps you load the file instead of require and load it everytime on you worker Thereby making it slower

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid it. But if you have many workers, you can make it easier by using `foreman` to start them with just one command.

Using foreman you can declare the various processes that are needed to run your application.

First, install foreman: `gem install foreman`

Then, create file named `Procfile` (without any extension).

In your `Procfile`:

```
worker-name1: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*
worker-name2: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*..
```

To start it, type this line: `foreman start`

You will see output like this:

```
17:21:48 worker-name1.1 | started with pid 20571
17:21:48 worker-name2.1 | started with pid 20573
```

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html